# Delegate only triggering one class, but not other classes that implement same protocol

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, delegates

I need some help in understanding how to implement a delegate so that all classes that implement the protocol gets a change to perform its actions based on protocol method(s) that gets triggered.

I have an InputHandler class(CCNode subclass) that takes care of all input and passes states (e.g.: FIRE, STOP, MOVE_LEFT, MOVE_RIGHT, etc). This InputHandler class has a Protocol that has some methods that it triggers based on UI controls that the player touches.

The problem is that right now I have two GameObjs that implement this protocol and perform its custom actions, but only one GameObject is triggering its actions while the other GameObj class is not performing its action.

If I comment the 2nd class' `controller.delegate = secondGameObj;` the first gameObj performs the actions as it is suppose to when the delegate triggers the protocol methods.

```
//InputHandler Class
@protocol InputHandlerDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
- (void)onPress;
- (void)onMove: (ControllerAction)state_;
- (void)onRelease;
@end

@class InputHandler: CCNode<CCTouchOneByOneDelegate>
@property (assign, nonatomic) id<InputHandlerDelegate> delegate;
//.....more InputHandler class details...
@end

//Implementation of game objects and assigning(registering) to the controller's delegate
InputHandler *controller = [InputHandler node];
[self addChild: controller];    

GameObject1 *gameObj1 = [GameObject1 node];
[self addChild: gameObj1];
controller.delegate = gameObj1; //does not trigger, unless I comment out gameObj2

GameObject2 *gameObj2 = [GameObject2 node];
[self addChild: gameObj2];
controller.delegate = gameObj2; //this game obj triggers protocol custom methods
```

Answer (score 0):

Your delegate property naturally stores a reference to a single object. When you assign the second delegate it replaces the first one. If you have a int variable X and assign it the value 10 followed by 5 then its value will be 5, not 10 *and* 5.

To allow multiple delegates, add them to an array with addDelegate and removeDelegate methods. To send a delegate message enumerate the array and send the message to each object. See for example cocos2d's CCTouchDispatcher.

Or at the least you need two separate delegate properties.

Comment: Thanks Steffen. I went thru the 1st & 3rd edtn of your book for help first b4 posting. I was almost going to implement a 2nd delegate, but that would just be a workaround. Instead of a delegate pattern, after some Googling found out about NSNotoficationCenter. The question I have is can I call [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName... multiple times in the class that was triggering the delegate methods. Also how to I remove it in the dealloc method, like removeObserver method.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question. I am a newbie (3-4 months in) learning Obj-C and Cocos2D/Box2D, coming from a C++/C# background, so this will seem like a doh moment for many experienced Objective-C++ devs.

I was using the Delegate Pattern to trigger classes that were interested in performing their custom actions based on the trigger. Delegate Pattern is a 1-to-1 relationship. One class triggers the event and the second class performs actions based on the trigger.

In Obj-C, there is an application singleton called NSNotificationCenter. This is a local notification/messaging system that allows a class to add a notification to this singleton instance, and other classes that are interested in performing its custom actions can register to notification and perform their custom actions. THink of it like adding a radio channel to a station. Anyone that wants to listen to that channel, just needs to dial into that channel frequency.

I also used a @protocol to make sure all classes listening to the notification had the same set of calls for consistency. E.g.: onPress, OnMove, onRelease, etc.